# fullPage js, separate autoscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, fullpage.js

I have problem with fullPage.js
I have 5 section and I want to separate the autoscroll, 
Section 1 to Section 3 use autoscroll and Section 4.1 to 4.2 use normal scroll
Any idea?
Here's my code

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var s, d;
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
      anchors: ['anchor1', 'anchor2', 'anchor3', 'anchor41', 'anchor42'],
      menu: '#menu',
      navigation: true,
      navigationPosition: 'right',
      navigationTooltips: ['First page', 'Second page', 'Third and last jump', 'Free', 'free!!'],
      onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
            leavingSection = $(this);
            console.log(leavingSection.prop('id'));
            s = leavingSection.data('scroller');
            if(direction == "up"){
              d = leavingSection.prev().data('scroller');
            }else if(direction == "down"){
              d = leavingSection.next().data('scroller');
            }
      },
      afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
        var loadedSection = $(this);
        if(s=="normal" && d=="auto"){
          $.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(true);
        }else if(s=="auto" && d=="normal"){
          $.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(false);
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.8.8/jquery.fullPage.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.8.8/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.8.8/vendors/scrolloverflow.min.js"></script>


<div id="fullpage">
      <div id="section1" class="container-fluid section" data-scroller="auto">
        <h1>Section 1</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="section2" class="container-fluid section" data-scroller="auto">
        <h1>Section 2</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="section3" class="container-fluid section" data-scroller="auto">
        <h1>Section 3</h1>
     </div>
      <div id="section41" class="container-fluid section" data-scroller="normal">
        <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="section42" class="container-fluid section" data-scroller="normal">
        <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

fullPage.js doesn't provide any solution for it. You'll have to code it yourself and probably won't be perfect.

The most you can do is use the function `setAutoScrolling` and turn autoScrolling on and off by using the callbacks but this will lead to undesirable results. 
Such as:

- autoScrolling from 1 to 2
- turn off autoScrolling in section 2 by using `onLeave` callback
- normal scroll from 2 onwards
- scrolling from 2 to 1 won't do it using `autoScrolling`, as you'll have to turn it on on the onLeave callback that will only get fired once the content of the 1st section in the viewport is bigger than the one from the 2nd section

[Reproduction online](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/1533/)

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
    fitToSection:false,
    //events
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        if (nextIndex ===1){
            $.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(true);
        }
        else if(nextIndex ===2){
            $.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(false);
        }
    },
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){},

});
```